# how to find this dynamic value? how to get this text(action for me ) & its dynamic value in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, automation

```html
<div _ngcontent-c8="" class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 mar-top-15 ng-star-inserted">
  <div _ngcontent-c8="" class="card card-style half shadow border-0 pointer mat-ripple" matripple="">
    <div _ngcontent-c8="" class="card-top">
      <h4 _ngcontent-c8="" class="card-text top-part top-tesxtarea" style="background-color: rgb(117, 65, 0);">Action For Me
        <mat-icon _ngcontent-c8="" class="none mat-icon mat-black material-icons" color="black" role="img" aria-hidden="true" id="display_2">grade</mat-icon>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c8="" class="card-buttom">
      <h1 _ngcontent-c8="" class="card-text buttom-number" id="count_2">11</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the phrases "Action for Me" and "grade" fixed (so you only need to extract `11`) or can all three be different on different occasions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have many of these div blocks and want to extract text from the one which grade is equal to `11` you can use expression like:

```
//h1[contains(@class,'buttom') and text()='11']/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/descendant::h4
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)